# Reading and writing image file as 'regular files'

Tags: python, image, byte

I am bound to using the `Python` standard library to read an image file, store its data in a variable, and then write a new image file containing the latter. I cannot simply copy nor move the image, but that does not matter. I also cannot use libraries such as PIL, I have to stick to `Python` 3.3.

I am reading the image content this way :

```
with open(image_path, mode='rb') as image_file:
    image_string = image_file.read()
```

And then writing the image content this way:

```
input_image = # value of the previous function
with open(new_image_path, mode='wb') as dest_image:
    dest_image.write(bytes(input_image, 'UTF-8'))
```

Yet the image file generated seems corrupted. A quick check with an hexadecimal editor shows that the data of my resulting image file has NOTHING to do with a regular PNG file, so I assume I am doing something really bad with the reading/writing part.

Comment: Have you tried just `dest_image.write(input_image)`?

Comment: Is the original image file actually encoded as UTF-8?

Comment: @Kevin : this result in a `TypeError` exception ('str' does no support the buffer interface)

Comment: @DavidReeve I don't know if images actually have an encoding (sorry, I know nothing in this field). I wrote this line because of the exception I just wrote in my previous comment, it seems Python was expecting bytes and not strings

Comment: Does it complain if you don't give it an encoding parameter?

Comment: @DavidReeve Yes, `TypeError : string argument without an encoding`

Comment: Wild guess: try replacing "UTF-8" with "ascii".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write the image_string, you don't need bytes as image_string is already a bytes object as you open using `'rb'`:

```
dest_image.write(image_string)

with open(image_path,'rb') as image_file:
    image_string = image_file.read()
    with open(new_image_path,'wb') as dest_image:
        dest_image.write(image_string)

print(type(image_string))
<class 'bytes'>
```